# What kind of array does PHP use?

Tags: php, arrays

I can define an `array` in PHP like this:

```
$array = array();
```

In C++, we have two kinds of array.

1. The first kind is a fixed size array, for example:

   ```
   int arr[4]; // 4 ints, hardcoded size
   ```
2. The second kind is a dynamic sized array

   ```
   std::vector<int> v; // can grow and shrink at runtime
   ```

What kind of array does PHP use? Are both kinds of arrays in PHP? If so, can you give me examples?

Comment: PHP uses numeric,associative arrays and multidimentional arrays. Arrays are dynamic in nature , no size should be mentioned . Go thorugh the link to find in detail . Its a vast topic to explain here 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: If you're used to C/C++ then a standard PHP "array" is actually a "hashmap", though more akin to your dynamic sized array.... though PHP does also provide [SPLFixedArray](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) though your normal array_* functions won't work with that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PHP is not as strict as C or C++. In PHP you don't need to specify the type of data to be placed in an array, you don't need to specify the array size either.

If you need to declare an array of integers in C++ you can do it like this:

`int array[6];`

This array is now bound to only contain integers. In PHP an array can contain just about everything:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = 1;
$arr[] = 2;
$arr[] = 3;
$arr[] = 4;
var_dump($arr);   //Prints [1,2,3,4]
$arr[] = 'hello world';   //Adding a string. Completely valid code
$arr[] = 3.14;   //Adding a float. This one is valid too
$arr[] = array(
           'id' => 128,
           'firstName' => 'John'
           'lastName' => 'Doe'
);  //Adding an associative array, also valid code
var_dump($arr);  //prints [1,2,3,4,'hello world',3.14, [ id => 128, firstName => 'John', lastName => 'Doe']]
```

If you're coming from a C++ background it's best to view the PHP array as a generic vector that can store everything.

Comment: so we can say all types of array in PHP dynamic size (like vector the size expand on runtime) ???@dimlucas

Comment: @sam Yes that's right. Another way you can view a PHP array is like a list of "pointers" (I use the word 'pointer' just for explanation, there is not a pointer type in PHP) to memory that can hold anything imagine, even an instance of a class. You can add or remove elements from anywhere in the array without breaking it. One more thing that I think you're going to find interesting is that you can ommit the `$arr = $array();` and my example code will still work. It's just the way PHP works

Comment: Your example with the multidimensional array is going to produces errors. You should quote your array keys whenever using non-int/float datatypes.

Answer (score 14):

From [php.net](http://php.net/array)

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several
>   different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash
>   table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack,
>   queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees
>   and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

Answer (score 3):

Basically there are **three Usage patterns** of array in PHP.

Indexed array: Arrays with sequential numeric index, such as 0, 1, 2, etc. Example:

```
$myarray = array();
$myarray[0] = "test data 1";
$myarray[1] = "test data 2";
$myarray[3] = "test data 3";
```

Associative array: This is the most frequently used type of PHP arrays whose elements are defined in key/value pair. Example:

```
$myarray = array();
$myarray["key1"] = "value 1";
$myarray["key2"] = "value 2";
$myarray["key3"] = "value 3";
```

Multidimensional array: Arrays whose elements may contains one or more arrays. There is no limit in the level of dimensions. Example:

```
$myarray = array();
$myarray[0] = array("data01","data02","data03");
$myarray[1] = array("data11","data12","data13");
```

For more details - Refer to *[PHP 5 Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)*.

Comment: **three type** is not correct. PHP only has one type of array and it can contain almost anything and can be treated in different ways.

Comment: @vsg24 agree with you

Comment: @VSG24 Technically speaking you are correct. I read this answer as just a introduction to the three types of structures that you will see in php.

Comment: @ManthanDave VSG was pointing out your answer is wrong.  If you agree your answer is wrong, please edit the errors out.

Comment: @Yakk answer is not wrong ,mainly three types of array in php is there you can check anywhere

Comment: @ManthanDave VSG24 stated "three types is not correct".  You responded "agree with you".  Now you are saying "there are three types".  You aren't being consistent.  "There is one type of array, and there are three common usage patterns" might be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

PHP uses three kinds of array:

Numeric array − An array with a numeric index. Values are stored and accessed in linear fashion.

Associative array − An array with strings as index. This stores element values in association with key values rather than in a strict linear index order.

Multidimensional array − An array containing one or more arrays and values are accessed using multiple indices.

Numeric Array Ex:

```
 $numbers = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Associative Array Ex:

```
$salaries = array("mohammad" => 2000, "qadir" => 1000, "zara" => 500);
```

Multidimensional Array Ex:

```
$marks = array( 
            "mohammad" => array (
               "physics" => 35,
               "maths" => 30,   
               "chemistry" => 39
            ),

            "qadir" => array (
               "physics" => 30,
               "maths" => 32,
               "chemistry" => 29
            ),

            "zara" => array (
               "physics" => 31,
               "maths" => 22,
               "chemistry" => 39
            )
         );
```

Answer (score 2):

A php array, in C++ terms, is roughly:

```
std::map< std::experimental::any, std::experimental::any >
```

where `std::experimental::any` is a type that can hold basically anything.  The php equivalent also can be sorted with the equivalent of `<`.

Well not quite -- closer to the truth is that a php array is an abstract interface that exposes much of the operations that the above `map` would provide in C++ (the C++ `map` is a concrete implementation).

Arrays with contiguous numeric keys stored in the Variant are treated much like a `std::vector<Variant>`, and under the interface the php system might even use `vector<Variant>` or something similar to store it, or even have two different internal details, one of which is for contiguous blocks of integer indexed data, and the other for sparse entries.  (I don't know how php is implemented, but that is how I would do it)

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses numeric, associative arrays, and multidimensional arrays. Arrays are dynamic in nature, and no size should be mentioned. Go through [php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to find details.

Comment: No, there is only ONE type of array in PHP, which behaves differently depending on how it is used.

Comment: Your answer, I'm afraid, does sound like you are saying there are 3 different types. I'm a native English speaker and I read it it that way, so you might want to reconsider your comment.

Comment: No it isn't , i should have mentioned that clearly .