# PHP: List within an associative array for CURL data

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am looking to make a request from [this API](https://api-docs.zoominfo.com/#c145dd01-eb54-4fc2-bbdb-9edc04b7ea1b) and am having some trouble.

The example request is:

```
curl --location 'https://api.zoominfo.com/enrich/contact'
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
--header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' --data '{"matchPersonInput": [{"firstName": "Henry","lastName": "Schuck","companyId": 346572700}],"outputFields": ["id","firstName","middleName","lastName"]}'
```

I am implementing this in PHP, here is my code

```
//ZoomInfo IP Enrich
function zoominfo_email_enrich() {  
    $zoominfo_token = $_GET['zoominfo_token'];
    $response = "";     

    $data = array(      
        "matchPersonInput" => array( 
            "emailAddress" => "test@gmail.com",
        ),
        "outputFields" => array(
            "id",
            "firstName",
            "middleName",
        )
    );

    $postdata = json_encode($data); 

    $ch = curl_init("https://api.zoominfo.com/enrich/contact");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization: ' . $zoominfo_token));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $response;
    die();
}
```

However, this call results in **error**: "MatchPersonInput should be a list".

I have also tried using

```
$data = array(      
    "matchPersonInput" => list( 
        "emailAddress" => "test@gmail.com",
    )
);
```

Which resulted in the WordPress site crashing.

What is the proper way to format this data in PHP to not get an error back?

Comment: Relevant reading: [What kind of array does PHP use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37543497/2943403) ...you already know how to declare an array, you merely don't know that a list is an alias for an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are expecting more than one value for this key, note their example input, it's wrapped in square braces:

```json
"matchPersonInput": [
    {"firstName": "Henry", "lastName": "Schuck", "companyId": 346572700}
]
```

This way, you can specify more than one record:

```json
"matchPersonInput": [
    {"firstName": "Henry", "lastName": "Schuck", "companyId": 346572700},
    {"firstName": "Mary", "lastName": "Wilbur", "companyId": 12345}
]
```

So even though you only have one `matchPersonInput` record in your code, you still need to make it into a list. In PHP terms, you need an indexed array of associative arrays. Just wrap your record in another layer of braces. I prefer the short array syntax for this:

```php
    $data = [
        "matchPersonInput" => [
            ["emailAddress" => "test@gmail.com"],
        ],
        "outputFields" => [
            "id",
            "firstName",
            "middleName",
        ]
    ];
```

Then, if you want to add additional matches:

```php
    $data = [
        "matchPersonInput" => [
            ["emailAddress" => "test1@gmail.com"],
            ["emailAddress" => "test2@gmail.com"],
            ["emailAddress" => "test3@gmail.com"],
        ],
        "outputFields" => [
            "id",
            "firstName",
            "middleName",
        ]
    ];
```